# NVIDIA graphics driver on Macbook Pro 10,1

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, mac, macbook-pro

I just installed 14.04 over my old 12.04 partition on my Macbook Pro 10,1 (which is dual-booting with OS X) by following the instructions [here](http://cberner.com/2014/04/20/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbook-pro-retina/). The only difference is that I'm using rEFInd instead of rEFIt. The proprietary NVIDIA drivers worked great with 12.04, but now I'm unable to boot into Unity with it in 14.04.

Generally, I just get a black screen after the Grub menu, though occasionally I get some kind of panic screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZynSB.jpg), where I see errors like:

```
[drm: __gen6_gt_force_wake_mt_get] *ERROR* Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear.
[drm: __gen6_gt_wait_for_thread_c0] *ERROR* GT thread status wait timed out
[drm: __intel_ring_setup_status_page] *ERROR* render ring: wait for SyncFlush to complete for TLB invalidation timed out
```

etc.

Using the nouveau drivers works fine, but everything feels sluggish so I would really like to get the NVIDIA drivers working.

Has anyone successfully gotten the NVIDIA drivers working with the GT-650M Mac Edition?

Comment: What driver version are you using? 331.79 lists GT 650M as supported (I didn't check any others).

Comment: To anyone who comes across this: I fixed the issue by installing the latest driver (337.12) straight from NVidia by following the instructions here: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/how-to-install-nvidia-337-12-graphics-driver-in-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

To get any picture at all, I chose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" in Grub, and bootet with the older kernel (3.11). Then I got it working according to this link:
http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=16696581#p16696581

It's for an Asus, but it's basically the same hardware and seems to work.
Only thing not working right now is brightness control.